# Java programming, arrays in functions

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So basically I have come across a situation in my programming where I need to ask the program to see if one part of an array is equal to any other parts of an array.

For instance if i have an array called array[5], and I needed to see if array[0] is equal to any of the other parts of the array, how would I do so? Assuming of course that I am getting input from the user, and I have to see if the user entered the same number.

Here is my real life example, this problem I am having is occurring in the `isUnique` method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week06_NelsonPimentel_Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] validnum;
        int i = 0;
        validnum = new int[5];
        boolean isvalid;
        boolean isunique;

        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 50 and 100");

        while (i < validnum.length) {
            validnum[i] = input.nextInt();

            if (validnum[i] <= 101 && validnum[i] >= 49) {
                isvalid = isValid(validnum[i]);
                if (i > 0) {
                    isunique = isUnique(validnum[i], validnum[i]);
                }
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid number***");
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean isValid(int a) {
        boolean b = true;
        System.out.println("valid");
        return b;
    }

    static boolean isUnique(int a, int b) {
        boolean yes;
        int i;
        if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("This is not a unique number");
            yes = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is a unique number!");
            yes = true;
        }
        return yes;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isunique = isUnique(validnum[i], validnum[i]);` will result in isunique being always `true`.

Comment: Uhm your code is confusing and for some reason `isValid` is always returning `true`.

Comment: so i switched isUnique(validnum[i], validnum[i]) to isUnique(validnum[i], validnum), would this make it so that validnum references all the values, and not just one?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over each element in the array and compare the current element with the new one:

```
if (i > 0) {
    isunique = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (validnum[i] == validnum[j]) {
            isunique = false;
            System.out.println(validnum[i] + " is not an unique number");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isunique == true) {
        System.out.println(validnum[i] + " is an unique number");
    }
}
i++;
```

Comment: unfortunately the way my professor wants this program submitted does not fit this format, HOWEVER your reply gives me an extremely good idea that I think should work, more or less I'll be implementing what you just taught me, but in a method, thank you for the response!

Comment: Yes, that's nearly the right approach. But he's already assigned the new value to the array. So you will always find a match!

Comment: @DiabolicWords not quite, please check: `j < i`.